# 3-links Robot Dynamic PD Computed Torque Control

Tags: control, dynamics

I am designing the PD control of 3-links robot using Simulink.

[image: Overall]

I can't figure out what to do in the 'Robot' block to get the acceleration d_qq back to calculate the error.

What is happening in this 'system' block?

[image: PD Control]

Comment: I'm afraid your question lacks a lot of details. Please take a moment to refine your question by adding more information. Also, stackoverflow allows you to upload pictures (i.e. no need for external links).

Answer (score 1):

You should develop the (forward) dynamic model of the manipulator. In fact, by definition, the problem that gives you the joint accelerations from the joint torques in called the Forward Dynamics problem. Which kind of 3 DOF manipulator is?